# Retrieving an integer value from a sqlite3 db (problem in obj-c)

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, integer, nsuinteger

In a sqlite3 database, I've a table "data" with two fields: type and path. The field type is defined as INTEGER. In this field I insert a NSUInteger value (which will be for example 0 or 1). The problem is that, when I retrieve it, I obtain a "strange" value. I don't know where I'm wronging.

```
   if (init_statement == nil) {
        const char *sql = "SELECT type,path FROM data WHERE id=?";
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &init_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }

    sqlite3_bind_int(init_statement, 1, primaryKey);

    if (sqlite3_step(init_statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
     int type = (int)sqlite3_column_text(init_statement, 0);
     char *relPath = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(init_statement, 1);

    // other stuff
    } 

    // Reset the statement for future reuse.
    sqlite3_reset(init_statement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite allows only 64 bit signed integers. You are assigning it an unsigned integer. Change it to NSInteger instead.

Comment: I change it to NSInteger. The right value is inserted, but when I retrieve it with the code above it's not so.

Comment: Why aren't you casting it back to `NSInteger`?

Comment: there is the same problem if I cast it. I'll do some other tests.

Comment: Why aren't you using `sqlite3_column_int64`?